# How can I move the cursor in a notebook using page up / page down?

Tags: front-end

When I am editing a notebook, currently when I hit the page up key, the cursor stays stationary. Same for page down.

**How can I connect page up / page down to the cursor?**

I want to be able to hit page up to go and edit something without using the mouse.

Comment: First step is to figure out what key that's bound to. Try using this: ``EventHandler[InputField[], "KeyDown" :> Print@FullForm[CurrentValue["EventKey"]]]``. Then use `NotebookEventActions` to bind the action to your notebook.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think the tough part is to move a coursor by 'page height' or to find the topmost visible cell.

Comment: @Kuba I wasn't sure if that's what they really wanted to do. If that is the case that will be a bit tricky.